# Костомизация изображения графика

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,9]
plt.plot(X_close, Y_close,color="#daff00") 
plt.plot(X_quantity, Y_quantity,color="#005aff")


ax = plt.axes()

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])


ax.set_facecolor("grey")

plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('testplot.png' ,dpi = 200)
```

В результате этого кода получается такое
( x_close,Y_close,X_quantity и Y_quantity массивы со значениями)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Можно ли одновременно убрать подписи значений осей, но при этом оставить сетку

2) можно ли убрать вокруг графика белую рамку, на которой были эти самые подписи к осям, мешает при сохранении файла как изображение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вместо

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

используйте

```
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

2) Перед сохранением файла используйте либо:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

либо добавьте в метод сохранения параметр **bbox_inches='tight'**:

```
plt.savefig('testplot.png' ,dpi = 200, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Это вряд ли уберет рамки полностью, конечно.

Можно ещё вручную указать поля:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, right=0.2, top=0.2, bottom=0.2)
```